# Calculating Value State matrix for a finite MDP without limit condition

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

In the book "Reinforcement Learning" From Andrew Sutton and Barto there is an example given for the Bellman equations:

> Figure 3.2 (left) shows a rectangular gridworld representation of a simple finite MDP. The cells of the grid correspond to the states of the environment. At each cell, four actions are possible: north, south, east, and west, which deterministically cause the agent to move one cell in the respective direction on the grid. Actions that would take the agent o↵ the grid leave its location unchanged, but also result in a reward of .1. Other actions result in a reward of 0, except those that move the agent out of the special states A and B. From state A, all four actions yield a reward of +10 and take the
>   agent to A0. From state B, all actions yield a reward of +5 and take the agent to B0

[image: Figure from book]

Then it continues:

> Suppose the agent selects all four actions with equal probability in all states. Figure 3.2
>   (right) shows the value function, v⇡, for this policy, for the discounted reward case with
>   gamma = 0.9. This value function was computed by solving the system of linear equations
>   (3.14). Notice the negative values near the lower edge; these are the result of the high
>   probability of hitting the edge of the grid there under the random policy.

3.14 equation being (so the state-value bellman equation):
[image: Value state equation]

I just wonder, without knowing when the task ends, how can we calculate the given matrix on figure 3.2?
And with that gamma, it will need a lot of iterations until we can ignore it.
Just trying to wrap my head around how to calculate each cell or if there is something I am ignoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task doesn't end.

In RL terms, **"value"** at state $s$ means the weighted *sum of **all** future rewards* when starting from state $s$ and following policy $\pi$. In this example the states will transit infinitely times.

Of course it's impossible to iterate infinitely times to calculate the **value**, that's why the Bellman equation $(3.14)$ is so important, because Bellman discovers that the **value**s (the wieghted sum of all future rewords) of different states satisfy a relation stated by $(3.14)$, which is basically a system of linear equations of the **value**s.

So to calculate the **value**s of the states, instead of iterating infinite times and accumulating the rewords for each state, you can simply solve the linear system and the result is there.

Comment: Yes, I understand that s why Bellman equation is relevant, but i guess i cant wrap my head around the math. Could you solve one cell of the value matrix ?

Comment: In this example you don't need any matrix algebra. The authors use matrix to represent the game board, each cell in the board corresponds to a state, there are 25 states in total. Bellman equation $(3.14)$ provides a linear system of 25 equations with 25 unknown values. Solve this linear system will get you the result.

Comment: ah, i got it know, it was just not productive to show that it just applied 3.14 for each s and a within the MDP process. Thanks